# Can't connect to MySQL using XAMPP and mysql connector

Tags: python, xampp, localhost, mysql-connector

Error: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)
Connection object is None

I am trying to connect to a database which is existing in the local host using XAMPP MySQL server and MySQL connector and encountering a error
i am facing this while trying to send a dictionary of values to local host and insert into the table present there using python
can anyone let me know how to solve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.